# spring boot security ldap authentication throws Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am a beginner for spring. Currently, I am trying to work on Spring LDAP authentication, but I am getting exception. Couldn't find a solution.

Sometimes I get this exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: domain.com:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: domain.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]

And also this:
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'uid=r.rashmi,ou=Users'

Can someone please help me, where am I going wrong.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

// AuthenticationManagerBuilder provides a mechanism to get a user based on the
// password encoder, datasource,
// userquery

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("ldap://domain.com:389/", "dc=domain,dc=com")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=Project").userSearchBase("dc=domain,dc=com ").userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
            .contextSource().url("ldap://domain.com:389/dc=domain,dc=com").and().passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder()).passwordAttribute("userPassword");

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();

}
```

}

ldapconfig.ldif

```
dn: ou=Users,ou=Project,dc=domain,dc=com

objectclass: user

userPassword: {SHA}hgjhghghg
```

application.properties

spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:ldapconfig.ldif

Is it not possible to authenticate without using .ldif?